# How to set a part of a box object with a diffrent color in three.js and the part dimension will get dynamically?

Tags: three.js

I am new to Three.js. This may be very basic question. But I tried to get a solution, unfortunately i didn't get any even from google. I have a 'mesh' with 'box geometry' and applied a 'MeshStandardMaterial' material. Specified a color in the material. Now I want show the part of this box is filled with some other color.This percentage of part will be dynamically.For example half of water filled in the glass the quantity of water will be get dynamically. 
I want to represent level of some filling.Another option to make some part of this box is transparent that is also fine.

```js
let cube_geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(tankWidth, tankHeight, tankDepth);
let ct_material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
                color: colourCode,
                metalness: 1.0,
                roughness: 0.5,
                transparent: true,
                opacity: params['CT Opacity'],
                alphaTest: 0.1
            });
cube.name = name;
let cube = new THREE.Mesh(cube_geometry , ct_material);

 
   group_ct.add(cube);//will add set of  boxes to this group
//---------------------------
function SetQty(qty)
{

 group_ct.traverse(function (tank) {

   if (tank instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

       tankName = tank.name;
       qty =GetQty(tankName);
       if(qty > 0) {
        //want to display filled level inside the box as per the quantity
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this.

The first and easiest is to create two cubes of your desired material, and scale them along the same axis. The difficulty there is that you would also need to recompute their position so they maintain the same barrier edge for the varying values of "percentage filled".

Another option that requires fewer calculations (but is more conceptually complex) is to employ [`Material.clippingPlanes`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.clippingPlanes) ([example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=cli#webgl_clipping)), and render your geometry using two different materials/meshes.

In the example below, I use the same cube geometry for both `Mesh` objects, but I use different materials with clipping planes pointing in opposite directions. I update their displacement in the render loop, which has the effect of changing the "fill".

```js
// three.js r110

const W = window.innerWidth
const H = window.innerHeight

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  alpha: true,
  antialias: true
})
renderer.setSize(W, H)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

// turn on clipping!
renderer.localClippingEnabled = true

const scene = new THREE.Scene()

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(28, W / H, 1, 1000)
camera.position.set(10, 20, 50)
camera.lookAt(scene.position)
scene.add(camera)

const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1)
//scene.add(light)
camera.add(light)

// define the clipping planes
const emptyClip = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), 0)
const fillClip = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0), 0)

const boxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 10, 10)

const emptyMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0x55ddff,
  metalness: 0,
  roughness: 0.2,
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0.5,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  clippingPlanes: [emptyClip]
})

const filledMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0xff5555,
  metalness: 0,
  roughness: 0.2,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  clippingPlanes: [fillClip]
})

const emptyMesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo, emptyMaterial)
scene.add(emptyMesh)
const filledMesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeo, filledMaterial)
scene.add(filledMesh)

// layer separator
const separatorGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10)
const separatorMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: 0xff5555,
  metalness: 0,
  roughness: 0.2,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide
})
const separator = new THREE.Mesh(separatorGeo, separatorMat)
separator.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2
scene.add(separator)

let count = 0

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)

  // compute the clipping plane displacement
  let displacement = Math.sin(count) * 0.5 // min = 25%, max = 75%
  displacement *= 5 // each cube side is 5 units

  // set the displacement of the planes (relative to their normals!)
  emptyMaterial.clippingPlanes[0].constant = displacement
  filledMaterial.clippingPlanes[0].constant = -displacement

  // update the separator
  separator.position.y = -displacement

  renderer.render(scene, camera)
  count += 0.05
}
animate()
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Jim,this code help me lot to implement the scenario.